# How to add child element with class ? through JS

Tags: element, new-operator

I have an element with the following id="loader-wrap"

```
<div id="loader-wrap"></div>
```

I want to add a new div element btw the above parent div automatically including add class "Pin" where ever I have this Id element.

Want this:  `<div id="loader-wrap"><div class="Pin"></div></div>`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I didn't try anything because I don't know how to do JS stuff. I have great expertise in CSS/HTML but not in JS. So I need some help regarding this. I usually copy scripts from the codepen. I can tweak though but unable to write anything from scratch. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use document.createElement() method:

```js
var pin = document.createElement("div"); // create new div
pin.setAttribute("class", "Pin"); // set class to the div

var loaderWrap = document.getElementById("loader-wrap"); // get the parent element
loaderWrap.appendChild(pin); // append the new div to the parent
```